Enemy AI Using NavMeshAgent Floats in Y Direction Instead of Following Player on Ground
I'm working on a Unity 3d project where I'm trying to create an enemy AI that follows the player using the NavMeshAgent + NavMeshsurface . However, I'm encountering an issue where the enemy character always floats in the sky along the Y-axis instead of following the player on the ground.
Here is my EnemyAI script:
enemy ai script:
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class EnemyAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player; // Reference to the player's position
    private NavMeshAgent agent; // Reference to the NavMesh Agent

    void Start()
    {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>(); // Get the NavMeshAgent component
    }

    void Update()
    {
        agent.SetDestination(player.position); // Set the destination to the player's position
    }
}


NavMesh Setup:
1- I have baked the NavMesh correctly on the ground.
2- The enemy has a NavMeshAgent + navMesh Surface  component attached.
Player Assignment:
The player Transform is correctly assigned in the Inspector.
Agent Settings:

Checked the agent's height and radius to ensure it fits the ground level.


theres a surface on the enemy? why? surfaces are ground, walls etc

@BugFinder i have updated the image , it was up flipped

As explained, the navmesh surface needs to be on the surface - in your case the plane..

Your ground Collider seems too large so the agent is probably walking on top of it ... Make sure your colliders match your visuals .. does your enemy have a Rigidbody? That could be the reason why it is pushed out of the Collider

@derHugo I tried to create an empty object then I added nav mesh surface and it work I really dont why and how just it work  :
